# Using jQuery to change quicktime controller from true to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicktime

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="248" height="198"><param name="src" value="media/MyMovie.mov">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">
<param name="controller" value="false">
<embed src="media/MyMovie.mov" width="248" height="198" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" type="video/quicktime" controller="true" autoplay="false"></embed></object>
```

I am using the following code to give each Quicktime movie a unique name attribute so I can use javascript to control it.

```
var VideoCounter = 0;
$('object embed[type*="video/quicktime"]').each(function(){
VideoCounter++
var MyTempVar = "themovie"+VideoCounter+"";
$(this).attr('name', MyTempVar);
});
```

What I also need to do is change the controller from true to false in both param name="controller" and embed using jQuery.

Inside my function i've tried

```
$(this).attr('controller','false');
```

and outside my function for the param i've tried variations on

```
$('object param[name*="controller"]').find('value="true"').replaceWith('value="false"');
```

and

```
$('object param[name*="controller"]').attr('value',$(this).attr('controller').replace('true','false')););
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is why they have video in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
function changemov(search, state){
    var tmp = $(search);
    tmp.find('embed:first').attr("controller", state);
    tmp.find('param[name="controller"]').val(state);
}
```

You would then invoke it with: `changemov('#player1', "false");`

I suppose you could also invoke like this if you didn't want to add an ID to your `<object>`:

```
changemov('object[classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"]', "false");
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Grallen, i've both those methods to invoke your function and a few other things and I still can't get that pesky control to hide.  I'm wondering if the Quicktime has already loaded with its controls before the jQuery changes the param so it doesn't end up effecting what's in the browser?